# Kotlin mix type

Tags: kotlin

How to limit the type instead of using Any in value of map?

```
val mixType = Map<String, String or Boolean or Int>()  // something I like
val anyType = Map<String, Any>()  // the scope is too large
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: For some secure reason, I will avoid to use Any type anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a [`sealed class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) here:

```
sealed class MyValue {
    class IntValue(val value: Int): MyValue()
    class BooleanValue(val value: String): MyValue()
    class StringValue(val value: Boolean): MyValue()
}
```